# Named pipes versus COM for IPC

Tags: performance, com, ipc, named-pipes

Are named pipes faster than using COM (out-of-proc) for inter-process communication?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is difficult to answer your question. With the information you have provided I would say - it depends. We need more information about the implementation scenario and the context of your requirement.

Despite this I would personally recommend using Named Pipes. They are relatively simple to set up, backward compatible and non-proprietary. Just make sure to wrap it in a layer of abstraction so that you can easily change to a different IPC method if needed.